# send mail with attachement in c# using outlook

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook

I m getting error when i m trying to send email to different Recipients with their respective attachment. i m using looping to change the Recipients and attachment but getting error. pls help to resolve this issue
my code is

```
private void BtnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] fileEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtPdfFiles.Text, "*.pdf");
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                if (RtxtBox.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please set Mail body text");
                    GrpMailBody.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    oMsg.HTMLBody = RtxtBox.Text;
                }
                if (RtxtSubject.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Mail Subject");
                    GrpMailBody.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    oMsg.Subject = RtxtSubject.Text;
                }

                String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
                int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;

                for (int i = 0; i <= grvExcelData.RowCount; i++)
                {

                    string EmaildID = grvExcelData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    string sFileName = grvExcelData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()+".pdf";
                    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(EmaildID);

                    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                    {
                        string fileN = "";
                        string xfileName;

                        xfileName=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                        if (xfileName == sFileName)
                        {
                            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@fileName, iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName); //getting error in this line

                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }

                    }
                    oRecip.Resolve();
                    oMsg.Send();
                    oRecip = null;
                    //oRecips = null;
                    oMsg = null;
                    oApp = null;

                }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it's giving error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: And which line of your code raise that error?

Answer (score 1):

**Add this--** 
**Add reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook**

```
 using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Set HTMLBody. 
            //add the body of the email
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "Hello!!";
            //Add an attachment.
            String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
            int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
            int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
            //now attached the file
            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\fileName.jpg", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
            //Subject line
            oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
            // Add a recipient.
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("EmailAddress");
            oRecip.Resolve();
            // Send.
            oMsg.Send();
            // Clean up.
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
        }//end of try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }//end of catch
    }//end of Email Method
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Outlook Inspector as described here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba/lLJwbwwl-XU/gRuQYRpJtxEJ

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

try
{
    string[] fileEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtPdfFiles.Text, "*.pdf");
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();   
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;

    // ...
}
```